# SonarQube - JS Dependencies Security Vulnerability Scanning

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube-scan, javascript-security

I have a large project which includes a front end portion downloading dependencies through NPM/Yarn and was looking for security vulnerability scanning for these third party dependencies defined in package.json.

I am already aware of options such as Snyk, retireJS, NSP (now acquired by NPM) and the like, however was wondering whether there is a decent plugin which I can use to add to SonarQube.  The idea would be to scan the list of dependencies, check it with a CVE database and generate an HTML report with the vulnerabilities identifying the level of risk for each one of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about using [OWASP Dependency Check](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Dependency_Check) and integrate the report into SonarQube using [this plugin](https://github.com/stevespringett/dependency-check-sonar-plugin)?

It would be using the info from NSP and RetireJS to do the scan.